# Application in CloudFoundry is able to access Redis even when Redis service is un-binded from that app

Tags: spring, redis, cloud-foundry

I have deployed an application in CloudFoundry with Redis service binded to it. In this app I have autowired StringRedisTemplate and have provided couple of endpoints for inserting, deleting and listing data from Redis.

Now when I am un-binding Redis service from my app , I am still able to perform all the operations to Redis. Whenever a service is un-binded its credentials ( Ip/port/username/password ) will not be there in the environment variables of that app. So my question is how still my app is able to access redis DB when redis service is un-binded from it ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you restage the app after un-binding? Changes to bindings don't take affect until after an app has been restaged. You can verify by running `cf env app-name` and seeing of the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable is still set.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually after binding Redis back I restage that app. But the issue here is that when I am un-binding Redis , still my app is able to query Redis.I checked after un-binding , redis details are not there in env  variable. So when the Redis is not available after un-binding then how my app is still able to do operations on that ? I have noticed that Redis has same password for all the apps it is binded to . So probably when the app starts it saves the ip,portand password somewhere and even when you un-bind Redis, app is able to use those saved credentials to access Redis.

Comment: CF doesn't get in between the app and the service, it just provides a means for the service's connection details to be exposed to the app via binding and VCAP_SERVICES. So if the service is still around after unbinding, with the same connection details and credentials, and the app someone remembers these details, then the app can continue to talk to the service.